# Hunter Controller immediately stops trying to water

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation

We used this controller last year and it was working fine. It is a Hunter SRC. Now, when I try to start a station, the controller immediately displays the time and appears that it is not trying to water anything. I switch it to "Manual - Single Station" and I see the station and the run time on the screen. Then I switch it to Run and it immediately displays the time and the water never turns on. I tried doing a factory reset and that didn't help. I can turn a station on manually at the valve itself and that works. Any ideas?

I just found this article that suggests I might just need to replace it: https://www.hunterindustries.com/support/src-controller-reverts-back-current-time

[image: Hunter Controller]